# How to return a private pointer to a list of pointers as const?

Tags: c++, constants, smart-pointers, private-members, container-data-type

I have a pointer to a list of pointers, as a private variable. I also have a getter that returns the pointer to the list. I need to protect it from changes.

I couldn't find how to use reinterpret_cast or const_cast on this.

```
class typeA{
    shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<typeB>>> l;
public:
   shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<const typeB>>> getList(){return (l);};
};
```

The compiler returns:

```
   error: could not convert ‘((typeA*)this)->typeA::x’ from ‘std::shared_ptr<std::__cxx11::list<std::shared_ptr<typeB> > >’ to ‘std::shared_ptr<std::__cxx11::list<std::shared_ptr<const typeB> > >’|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

It seems as    `const shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<typeB>>>` and   `shared_ptr<const list<shared_ptr<typeB>>>` work fine.

Is it possible to do return `l` as a complete const, like:

```
const shared_ptr<const list<shared_ptr<const typeB>>>
```

or at least like:

```
shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<const typeB>>>
```

?

References instead of pointers is not an option. To declare `l` as `shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<const typeB>>>` also is not a wanted solution.

EDIT: no 'int' anymore.

It seems as it is not possible exactly what I wanted, but the suggested solutions are good. Yes, copying pointers is acceptable.

My bad i didn't put typeB immediately. I am aware of some advantages of references over pointers, but  I hoped there is some similar solution.

Comment: I'm more curious why you have a pointer to a container? What's the use-case for that? And why do you have a container of pointers to `int`? What's the use-case for that?

Comment: This is not Java. Your code looks suspicious.

Comment: how about just `list<int>`? Why is that not a wanted solution?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Unless there's some special requirements, `std::vector<int>` is preferable IMO.

Comment: In my code I have a lot of procedures that create object and return it. The only way to do this is to return by value or return a pointer. The former is expensive. In this case I do not need a pointer to container, but I do not want to mix references and pointers. It is easier and cleaner to have just pointers.

Comment: I think you might need to [get a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and read about *references*. And having pointers to single `int` values is pointless (no pun intended).

Comment: I put 'int' to be more easy to read, but I can change.

Comment: I was afraid of comments like this. The point is not int. The point is what I asked.

Comment: This appears to be an [x y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you ask about your original problem, you may find a better solution then trying to get this complex solution working.

Comment: @HD2000 I thought already you might intend to use int as placeholder for some larger object... But if you explain explicitly before presenting the code, people know... On the other hand, if you wrote `shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<TypeB>>>`, matter would have been clear as well. Although better if you did, I'd even accept not pre-declaring `TypeB` in this very specific case as it's still clear what you intend to ask...

Comment: @Fox: Maybe it is an XY problem, but nevertheless it does not hurt to answer, if there is a solution, or to say that there is no solution.

Comment: @HD2000 The point about XY problems is: We might present you something properly solving the problem you presented, just to let you discover afterwards that whatever you try to do still does not work... Or you get a solution much more complex than necessary; imagine you present us: *'I want to sum up all elements in a vector'* - and invisible to us, you fill the vector with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., n. If you instead asked *'I want to sum up first n natural numbers'*, you'd have gotten the well known formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new list of `const int`'s from your original list and return that:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::list<std::shared_ptr<const int>>> getList(){
    return std::make_shared<std::list<std::shared_ptr<const int>>>(l->begin(), l->end());
}
```

If you want to prevent people from making changes to the returned list, make it const too:

```
std::shared_ptr<const std::list<std::shared_ptr<const T>>> getList(){
    return std::make_shared<const std::list<std::shared_ptr<const T>>>(l->cbegin(), l->cend());
}
```

The shared pointer returned by this function does not point to the original list but to the newly created list.

An alternative may be to provide iterators that, when dereferenced, returns `const T&` (where *T* is the type you actually store). That way there will be no need to copy the whole list every time you want to go though it. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

struct example {
    int data;
    example(int x) : data(x) {}
};

template <class T>
class typeA {
    std::shared_ptr<std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>> l = std::make_shared<std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>>();
public:
    template< class... Args >
    void add( Args&&... args ) {
        l->emplace_back(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    // a very basic iterator that can be extended as needed   
    struct const_iterator {
        using uiterator = typename std::list<std::shared_ptr<T>>::const_iterator;
        uiterator lit;
        const_iterator(uiterator init) : lit(init) {}
        const_iterator& operator++() { ++lit; return *this; }
        const T& operator*() const { return *(*lit).get(); }
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return lit != rhs.lit; }
    };

    const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(l->cbegin()); }
    const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return const_iterator(l->cend()); }
    auto begin() const noexcept { return cbegin(); }
    auto end() const noexcept { return cend(); }
};

int main() {
    typeA<example> apa;
    apa.add(10);
    apa.add(20);
    apa.add(30);
    for(auto& a : apa) {
        // a.data = 5; // error: assignment of member ‘example::data’ in read-only object
        std::cout << a.data << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: it will not share reference counter with the original `shared_ptr` though

Comment: Your use of the list constructor is more concise than my transform +1. But it might be good to make clear that the shared pointer that you return does not point to the same list as `l` does.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: I think best would be making the list itself const as well - as dealing with two different lists, not allowing to modify the copy will prevent the user to insert new elements while assuming having modified the original...

Comment: @HD2000 I added an alternative that doesn't require copying the list at all.

Comment: @Aconcagua True! Added that option too.

Comment: @Aconcagua I just noticed your answer and I find that much better than mine. I'll leave this comment for future archaeologists. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a pointer-to-nonconst to a pointer-to-const, you have two pointers. Furthermore, a list of pointers-to-nonconst is a completely different type from a list of pointers-to-const.

Thus, if you want to return a pointer to a list of pointers-to-const, what you must have is a list of pointers-to-const. But you don't have such list. You have a list of pointers-to-nonconst and those list types are not interconvertible.

Of course, you could transform your pointers-to-nonconst into a list of pointers-to-const, but you must understand that it is a separate list. A pointer to former type cannot point to the latter.

So, here is an example to transform the list (I didn't test, may contain typos or mistakes):

```
list<shared_ptr<const int>> const_copy_of_list;
std::transform(l->begin(), l->end(), std::back_inserter(const_copy_of_list),
               [](auto& ptr) {
    return static_pointer_cast<const int>(ptr);
});
// or more simply as shown by Ted:
list<shared_ptr<const int>> const_copy_of_list(l->begin(), l->end());
```

Since we have created a completely new list, which cannot be pointed by `l`, it makes little sense to return a pointer. Let us return the list itself. The caller can wrap the list in shared ownership if the need it, but don't have to when it is against their needs:

```
 list<shared_ptr<const int>> getConstCopyList() {
      // ... the transorm above
      return const_copy_of_list;
 }
```

Note that while the list is separate, the pointers inside still point to the same integers.

---

As a side note, please consider whether shared ownership of an `int` object makes sense for your program - I'm assuming it is a simplification for the example.

Also reconsider whether "References instead of pointers is not an option" is a sensible requirement.

Comment: From everything, this seems as the closest solution. Thanks.

Comment: @HD2000 Caleth's is better from practical point of view (you can keep using `list` if you need it, but consider whether you actually need a `list`). Mine just follows the arbitrary "no references" requirement. And Ted's use of constructor is simpler than my transform, you can use it without returning a shared pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You problem squarely lies at

> but I do not want to mix references and pointers. It is easier and cleaner to have just pointers.

What you are finding here is that statement is *wrong*. A `list<TypeB>` can bind a `const list<TypeB> &` reference, and none of the list's members will allow any modification of the `TypeB` objects.

```
class typeA {
    std::vector<typeB> l;
public:
    const std::vector<typeB> & getList() const { return l; };
};
```

If you *really really* must have `const typeB`, you could instead return a *projection* of `l` that has added `const`, but that wouldn't be a [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container), but instead a [*Range*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges) (using the `ranges` library voted into C++20, see also [its standalone implementation](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3))

```
std::shared_ptr<const typeB> add_const(std::shared_ptr<typeB> ptr)
{
    return { ptr, ptr.get() };
}

class typeA {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<typeB>> l;
public:
    auto getList() const { return l | std::ranges::transform(add_const); };
};
```

Another alternative is that you can wrap your `std::shared_ptr`s in something like [`std::experimental::propagate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const), and just directly return them.

Comment: If applying this to a list or vector of pointers, const-ness will only apply to these, but not the objects pointed to. Question is: why should there be a list of pointers at all? Well, it might be a polymorphic scenario where `TypeB` is just the base class...

Comment: It is easy to combine raw pointers and references, while it is not possible to do it with smart pointers. So if I have a bunch of procedures dealing with pointers, inserting references is another difficulty, at least for me.

Comment: @HD2000 I don't follow. You have to create new pointer objects for both raw and smart pointers when switching between `ptr<T>` and `ptr<const T>`. What you should instead prefer is dealing with references (and reference-like wrappers) as much as possible

Comment: No I am just saying why I am not using references - easier to use pointers all the time, then to think about if some object is pointer or not, and how to turn one into another.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is a VERY complex construct:

```
shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<typeB>>> l;
```

This is three levels of indirection, of which two have reference counting lifetime management, and the third is a container (and not memory-contiguous at that).

Naturally, given this complex structure, it is not going to be easy to convert it to another type:

```
shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<const typeB>>>
```

Notice that `std::list<A>` and `std::list<const A>` are two distinct types by design of standard library. When you want to pass around non-modifying handles to your containers, you are usually supposed to use `const_iterator`s.
In your case there is a `shared_ptr` on top of the `list`, so you can't use iterators if you want that reference counting behavior.

At this point comes the question: do you REALLY want that behavior?

- Are you expecting a situation where your `typeA` instance is destroyed, but you still have some other `typeA` instances with the same container?
- Are you expecting a situation where all your `typeA` instances sharing the container are destroyed, but you still have some references to that container in other places of your runtime?
- Are you expecting a situation where the container itself is destroyed, but you still have some references to some of the elements?
- Do you have any reason at all to use `std::list` instead of more conventional containers to store shared pointers?

If you answer YES to all the bullet points, then to achieve your goal you'll probably have to design a new class that would behave as a holder for your `shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<typeB>>>`, while only providing `const` access to the elements.

If, however, on one of the bullet points your answer is NO, consider redesigning the `l` type. I suggest starting with `std::vector<typeB>` and then only adding necessary modifications one by one.

Comment: The problem with the const-iterator rather is that it makes the shared_ptr const, but not the pointee... The iterator itself would be fine: As with all iterators, these can get invalidated under certain circumstances. You don't need the iterator itself to take part in reference counting - as long as it is valid, the shared pointer yet exists, thus the reference *is* yet counted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with templates is that for any

```
template <typename T>
class C { };
```

any two pairs `C<TypeA>` and `C<TypeB>` are totally unrelated classes – this is even the case if `TypeA` and `TypeB` only differ in `const`-ness.

So what you actually want to have is technically not possible. I won't present a new workaround for now, as there *are* already, but try to look a bit further: As denoted in comments already, you *might* be facing a XY problem.

Question is: What would a user do with such a list? She/he might be iterating over it – or access single elements. Then why not make your entire class look/behave like a list?

```
class typeA
{
    // wondering pretty much why you need a shared pointer here at all!
    // (instead of directly aggregating the list)
    shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<typeB>>> l;
public:
    shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<typeB>>>::const_iterator begin() { return l->begin(); }
    shared_ptr<list<shared_ptr<typeB>>>::const_iterator end() { return l->end(); }
};
```

If you used a vector instead of a list, I'd yet provide an index operator:

```
shared_ptr<typeB /* const or not? */> operator[](size_t index);
```

Now one problem yet remains unsolved so far: The two `const_iterators` returned have an immutable shared pointer, but the pointee is still mutable!

This is a bit of trouble - you'll need to implement your own iterator class now:

```
class TypeA
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
        std::list<std::shared_ptr<int>>::iterator i;         
        public:
        // implementation as needed: operators, type traits, etc.
    };
};
```

Have a look at [`std::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) for a full example – be aware, though, that `std::iterator` is deprecated, so you'll need to implement the type-traits yourself.

The iterator tag to be used would be `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag` or `random_access_iterator_tag` (`contiguous_iterator_tag` with C++20), if you use a `std::vector` inside.

Now important is how you implement two of the needed operators:

```
std::shared_ptr<int const> TypeA::iterator::operator*()
{
    return std::shared_ptr<int const>(*i);
}

std::shared_ptr<int const> TypeA::iterator::operator->()
{
    return *this;
}
```

The other operators would just forward the operation to the internal iterators (increment, decrement if available, comparison, etc).

I do not claim this is the Holy Grail, the path you need to follow under all circumstances. But it is a valuable alternative worth to at least consider...